# Allowing the same member group to create entries for certain channels but being able to edit all channels

Tags: members, ee3

(V3.5.11)

I am not sure whether this can be done but I am wondering if the same member is able to create entries on certain channels but is able to edit all channels.

I know there are check boxes in the "Member Groups CP" like below:

[image]

So for example; I want the client to edit the homepage channel but I don't want them to create a new entry on that same channel.

Is that possible?

Thanks
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to prevent a user from making subsequent entries in the "Home Page" channel, you can limit the amount entries permitted in the channel to "1", or whatever amount you want. They'll have access to edit existing entry(ies), but not to make any new ones past the limit set.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/channel/form.html#maximum-number-of-entries

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i have limited the entries to 1 but it still shows the most recent entry instead of my original?

Comment: Recent vs. original?...shows it how/where? Details will get you everywhere.

Comment: Sorry for not being more descriptive. Basically I have one entry in the homepage channel which contents the content for that page but if I add in another entry in the homepage channel it overwrites the "oldest" entry. But basically I just want the client to be able to create entries for certain channels but be able to edit all the channels under one member group. Hope that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: If you want to pick and choose alternative permissions for one user group depending on channel, you'll have to find a 3rd party solution. EE doesn't get that granular out-of-the-box.

Comment: Ok thank you for getting back to me. Could your recommend a 3rd party app? Point me in the right direction. Thanks